TypeError: cacheManager.caching is not a function
"cache-manager": "^6.1.3",
@Module({
  imports: [CacheModule.register({ ttl: 604800000 })],
  controllers: [AreaController],
  providers: [AreaService, PrismaService],
})
export class AreaModule {}

@Get()
  @CacheTTL(604800000)
  @UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
  async getAll(): Promise<city[]> {
    return await this.areaService.getAll();
  }

[Nest] 22452  - 2024/11/18 15:12:03   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] cacheManager.caching is not a function
TypeError: cacheManager.caching is not a function

please report this to https://github.com/nestjs/cache-manager/issues instead.

Use v5 of cache-manager to fix this problem.
Using npm:
npm i @nestjs/cache-manager cache-manager@5.x.x


This is currently the solution since v6 still have not fixed the integration within NestJS
